# How to delete 7 days old backup files from s3 keeping only one file?

Tags: bash, cron, s3cmd

I am taking and uploading mongodb backup on s3 every two hours with cron.

```
17 */2 * * *
```

Now I want to keep all files of last 7 days, and want to delete all files from s3 after 7 days but want to keep one backup for 1 day.

I am using S3cmd.

How can I do that?

Comment: please elaborate on keeping 1 day backup; according to what I have understood: `find ./ -mtime +1 -exec rm -rf {} \;`

Comment: Thanks for your reply.
 
After reading few other articles I fixed it myself.
I used 
   **s3cmd ls s3://$S3_BUCKET_NAME |awk "/$WEEK_AGO-*/"**
 to list all files and then delete them one by one.